# the scope of private class methods in an anonymous function

Tags: php, lambda, private

Following code which does not work as expected , it more accurate comments below in the code

```
class A1 {
    function __call($name, $arguments)    {
        throw new \Exception('Method ..... ' . $name . ' not exists ...');
    }

    /* When this method is public - it works good*/
    private function test($d) {
        var_dump($d);
    }

    public function test1() {
        /* duplicate for using in anonym function */
        $_this=$this;

        #$_this->test(1); #- it works good!!!
        #var_dump($_this);

        /* create anonym func, wherein the method is called test() */
        $rrr= function()use($_this){
            #var_dump($_this); # - values of output equally with above used var_dump
            $_this->test(1); # - it do NOT WORK !!!!
        };

        $rrr();  # catch Exception of __call() ...
    }
}

$r = new A1;
var_dump($r->test1());
```

I can't understand why the anonymous function call counts as from the OUTSIDE, when $this it is not changed ...

bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$this` doesn't exist when the class is compiled (only when it has been instantiated) it can't be passed via `use`; you have to bind `$this` to your closure at run-time:

```
class A1 {
    function __call($name, $arguments)    {
        throw new \Exception('Method ..... ' . $name . ' not exists ...');
    }

    /* When this method is public - it works good*/
    private function test($d) {
        var_dump($d);
    }

    public function test1() {
        /* create anonym func, wherein the method is called test() */
        $rrr= function(){
            $this->test(1);
        };
        Closure::bind($rrr, $this);
        $rrr();  # catch Exception of __call() ...
    }
}

$r = new A1;
$r->test1();
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/CdFfee)

or pass it as a run-time argument rather than a `use` argument:

```
class A1 {
    function __call($name, $arguments)    {
        throw new \Exception('Method ..... ' . $name . ' not exists ...');
    }

    /* When this method is public - it works good*/
    private function test($d) {
        var_dump($d);
    }

    public function test1() {
        /* create anonym func, wherein the method is called test() */
        $rrr= function($this){
            $this->test(1);
        };
        $rrr();  # catch Exception of __call() ...
    }
}

$r = new A1;
$r->test1();
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/4WvVJo)

Comment: Mark Baker, thank you! it is works! but it had to upgrade the system and the version of php, but it's the little things )